# Opera: avoid wait cursor during img-src-refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, image, refresh, opera

On a web page, I have an image continuously be refreshed by updating the src-attribute of the corresponding img-tag. This seems to work very well with a broad range of browsers. However, in Opera 10.51/WinXP/32, every time the image is updated, for a fraction of a second, the wait cursor is shown. It may confuse users.

So, how do I get rid of the wait/hour-glass cursor?

What I briefly tried, hoping to find a work around: I created a new img-node, not yet in the DOM, and set the src-attribute of that node. However, even in that case, Opera shows the wait cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in a nice way, sorry. An ugly way might be to pre-fetch the image with XMLHttpRequest but I think it's too ugly to consider :-p

Comment: I forgot to mention: If I recall correctly, I tried out your proposal, and unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Well, it's just not possible I guess.. :-/